# A more streamlined approach than nested for loops to fill an array in R

Tags: r, arrays, for-loop, apply

I'm trying to write a function in R that models population sizes (of different age brackets) across a network of connected populations. As a simplified example, imagine I want to predict how many juveniles and adults there are in 2 separate populations, over 10 discrete time steps:

```
age <- c("juvenile","adult")
pop<-c(1:2)
t <- c(1:10)
```

I make an empty 3D array to fill, and set starting (t=1) population sizes of 2 and 4.

```
a1 <- array(0, dim=c(10,2,2), dimnames = list(t, age,pop))
a1[1,2,1:2] <- c(2, 4)
```

And then I've written a function to fill this array from t=2 to t=10:

```
f1 <- function(a1){
  for(t in 2:10){
    for(p in 1:2){
    a1[t,1,1] <- a1[t-1,2,1] * 2
    a1[t,2,1] <- a1[t-1,1,1] + (a1[t-1,2,1] * 0.5)
    
    a1[t,1,2] <- a1[t-1,2,2] * 3
    a1[t,2,2] <- a1[t-1,1,2] + (a1[t-1,2,2] * 0.25)
    }
  }
  return(data.frame(a1))
}

f1(a1)
```

Between each time step:

1. juveniles become adults,
2. adults produce more juveniles (either 2 or 3 per adult, depending on population), and
3. a proportion of adults (either 0.5 or 0.25, depending on pop) survive to the next time step.

I quite like this methodical approach, but in reality my array has many more dimensions, all of different lengths, that are all inter-connected. In other words, a whole lot of nested for loops and excessive array co-ordinates (it gets tricky to remember what something like `a1[t,3,1,2,1]` is actually referring to).

If anyone has any suggestions on where to start for a more streamlined approach, that would be greatly appreciated. I keep hearing how `apply` functions are more concise than for loops, but I've only been able to find examples on how to use `apply` to summarise arrays, rather than use it to fill them.